# Thumbnail images not reducing image size

Tags: php, android, iphone

I am doing and IOS and android app that contains image gallery, i need to show all image thumbs in the bottom with vertical scroller.My web side is developing using PHP , they created thumbs from web but it cant reduce image size.My gallery page is crashing due to high image size.

Am looking a good php or javascript library that create thumbs and reduces image size.

Help is highly appreciable,

Thanks,
VKS.

Comment: This might not answer the original question. But in android you can also reduce the size from your image to the desired dimensions. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, boolean)

Comment: Use Jpeg compression, reduce size to something around 100x100, and store only 10 items at a time, request again for additional items.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
where path is the adress of the picture on your phone.

```
public Bitmap getImage(String path) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        int srcWidth = options.outWidth;
        int srcHeight = options.outHeight;
        int[] newWH = new int[2];
        newWH[0] = srcWidth / 2;
        newWH[1] = (newWH[0] * srcHeight) / srcWidth;

        int inSampleSize = 1;
        while (srcWidth / 2 >= newWH[0]) {
            srcWidth /= 2;
            srcHeight /= 2;
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }

        // float desiredScale = (float) newWH[0] / srcWidth;
        // Decode with inSampleSize
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap sampledSrcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        int newh = (srcWidth * sampledSrcBitmap.getHeight())
                / sampledSrcBitmap.getWidth();
        Bitmap r = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sampledSrcBitmap, srcWidth, newh,
                true);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(r, 0, 0, srcWidth, newh,
                matrix, true);

        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```